# Merging Individual arrays on basis of keys

Tags: php

I have following two arrays dynamically growing.

First array

```
    Array
    (
    [Development Fund] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [LedgerID] => 573befb96e3dceb6468b4567
                    [LedgerName] => Development Fund
                    [PanITNO] => UK07AK1787
                    [dateOfPayment] => 01-Dec-2015
                    [totalAmountPaid] => 49000
                    [tdsRate] => 2
                    [totalDudections] => 980
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [LedgerID] => 573befb96e3dceb6468b4567
                    [LedgerName] => Development Fund
                    [PanITNO] => UK07AK1787
                    [dateOfPayment] => 01-Mar-2016
                    [totalAmountPaid] => 4000
                    [tdsRate] => 2
                    [totalDudections] => 80
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [LedgerID] => 573befb96e3dceb6468b4567
                    [LedgerName] => Development Fund
                    [PanITNO] => UK07AK1787
                    [dateOfPayment] => 23-Mar-2016
                    [totalAmountPaid] => 19000
                    [tdsRate] => 2
                    [totalDudections] => 380
                )

        )

    [Registration Fee] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [LedgerID] => 5739b50b6e3dce450e8b4567
                    [LedgerName] => Registration Fee
                    [PanITNO] => ITR00123
                    [dateOfPayment] => 02-Jan-2016
                    [totalAmountPaid] => 1000
                    [tdsRate] => 10
                    [totalDudections] => 100
                )

        )

    [Purchase1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [LedgerID] => 573c321e6e3dcec3228b4567
                    [LedgerName] => Purchase1
                    [PanITNO] => ITR00123
                    [dateOfPayment] => 02-Jan-2016
                    [totalAmountPaid] => 8000
                    [tdsRate] => 2
                    [totalDudections] => 160
                )

        )

)
```

Second array

```
 Array
(
    [Development Fund] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (                    
                [Amountdeposited] => 1000
                [dateOfDeposited] => 01-Jan-2016
                [challaNumber] => 2
            )

        [1] => Array
            (                    
                [Amountdeposited] => 50000000
                [dateOfDeposited] => 03-Mar-2016
                [challaNumber] => 5555
            )

        [2] => Array
            (                   
                [Amountdeposited] => 90000
                [dateOfDeposited] => 24-Mar-2016
                [challaNumber] => 999
            )

    )
```

)

I need output Like follows, on the basis of key.

Final array

```
    Array
    (
    [Development Fund] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [LedgerID] => 573befb96e3dceb6468b4567
                    [LedgerName] => Development Fund
                    [PanITNO] => UK07AK1787
                    [dateOfPayment] => 01-Dec-2015
                    [totalAmountPaid] => 49000
                    [tdsRate] => 2
                    [totalDudections] => 980
                    [Amountdeposited] => 1000
                    [dateOfDeposited] => 01-Jan-2016
                    [challaNumber] => 2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [LedgerID] => 573befb96e3dceb6468b4567
                    [LedgerName] => Development Fund
                    [PanITNO] => UK07AK1787
                    [dateOfPayment] => 01-Mar-2016
                    [totalAmountPaid] => 4000
                    [tdsRate] => 2
                    [totalDudections] => 80
                    [dateOfDeposited] => 03-Mar-2016
                    [challaNumber] => 5555
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [LedgerID] => 573befb96e3dceb6468b4567
                    [LedgerName] => Development Fund
                    [PanITNO] => UK07AK1787
                    [dateOfPayment] => 23-Mar-2016
                    [totalAmountPaid] => 19000
                    [tdsRate] => 2
                    [totalDudections] => 380
                    [Amountdeposited] => 90000
                    [dateOfDeposited] => 24-Mar-2016
                    [challaNumber] => 999
                )

        )

    [Registration Fee] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [LedgerID] => 5739b50b6e3dce450e8b4567
                    [LedgerName] => Registration Fee
                    [PanITNO] => ITR00123
                    [dateOfPayment] => 02-Jan-2016
                    [totalAmountPaid] => 1000
                    [tdsRate] => 10
                    [totalDudections] => 100
                )

        )

    [Purchase1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [LedgerID] => 573c321e6e3dcec3228b4567
                    [LedgerName] => Purchase1
                    [PanITNO] => ITR00123
                    [dateOfPayment] => 02-Jan-2016
                    [totalAmountPaid] => 8000
                    [tdsRate] => 2
                    [totalDudections] => 160
                )

        )

)
```

Please suggest if it's possible to do it using any PHP built-in function.

Comment: Umm did you mean to repeat "Please suggest is is possible any PHP direct function. its urgent for me." I don't think anyone will like that very much. I wouldn't be surprised if someone downvotes your question for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. To concatenate the arrays, `$arr1+$arr2` will work. But it is not working in your case. Array_merge, recursive merge and combine none of them are working in your case. So try to use for loop to merge them.

```
foreach ($arr1 as $key1 => $value1) {
   if($key1 == 'Development Fund') {
      foreach($arr2['Development Fund'] as $key2 => $value2){
        array_push($arr1['Development Fund'][$key2],$value2);
     }
   }
}
```

But this will give you result like this

```
Array
(
    [Development Fund] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [LedgerID] => 573befb96e3dceb6468b4567
                    [LedgerName] => Development Fund
                    [PanITNO] => UK07AK1787
                    [dateOfPayment] => 01-Dec-2015
                    [totalAmountPaid] => 49000
                    [tdsRate] => 2
                    [totalDudections] => 980
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [Amountdeposited] => 1000
                            [dateOfDeposited] => 01-Jan-2016
                            [challaNumber] => 2
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [LedgerID] => 573befb96e3dceb6468b4567
                    [LedgerName] => Development Fund
                    [PanITNO] => UK07AK1787
                    [dateOfPayment] => 01-Mar-2016
                    [totalAmountPaid] => 4000
                    [tdsRate] => 2
                    [totalDudections] => 80
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [Amountdeposited] => 50000000
                            [dateOfDeposited] => 03-Mar-2016
                            [challaNumber] => 5555
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [LedgerID] => 573befb96e3dceb6468b4567
                    [LedgerName] => Development Fund
                    [PanITNO] => UK07AK1787
                    [dateOfPayment] => 23-Mar-2016
                    [totalAmountPaid] => 19000
                    [tdsRate] => 2
                    [totalDudections] => 380
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [Amountdeposited] => 90000
                            [dateOfDeposited] => 24-Mar-2016
                            [challaNumber] => 999
                        )

                )

        )

    [Registration Fee] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [LedgerID] => 5739b50b6e3dce450e8b4567
                    [LedgerName] => Registration Fee
                    [PanITNO] => ITR00123
                    [dateOfPayment] => 02-Jan-2016
                    [totalAmountPaid] => 1000
                    [tdsRate] => 10
                    [totalDudections] => 100
                )

        )

    [Purchase1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [LedgerID] => 573c321e6e3dcec3228b4567
                    [LedgerName] => Purchase1
                    [PanITNO] => ITR00123
                    [dateOfPayment] => 02-Jan-2016
                    [totalAmountPaid] => 8000
                    [tdsRate] => 2
                    [totalDudections] => 160
                )

        )

)
```

Is that OK for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
function MergMultiDmsAry($array1,$array2)
{

$i = 0;
$newa = array();
$god = array();
$final = array();

foreach($array1 as $key=>$value)
{
   for($j = 0; $j < count($value); $j++)
     {
        $newa = array_merge($value[$j],$array2[$key][$j]);
        $god[] = $newa;

}   

$i++;

    // set the key 
    $final[$key] = $god;    
}


print_r($final);
```

}

```
$data = array('dev'=>array(array('id'=>1),array('id'=>2)));
$data2 =       array('dev'=>array(array('name'=>'john','address'=>'damak'),array('name'=>'mayer','address'=>'kathmandu')));

MergMultiDmsAry($data,$data2);
```

This will might help you

Comment: you have 2 answer here.you can edit your answer and add second answer to first.

Answer (score 0):

Gave me answer:

```
Array ( [dev] =>  Array 
       ( [0] => 
           Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => john [address] => damak ) 
        [1] =>
         Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => mayer [address] => kathmandu ) 
) )
```